# How can I start a Nodejs RESTful Service on my VPS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, centos, vps

I have already done these steps:

1. Write a simple RESTful service use node. (It works fine on my localhost.)
2. Push these code to Github(https://github.com/HotHunter/VirginBlog/tree/develop/Server).
3. Deploy a VPS(CentOS) on Vultr.com. IP: 45.76.212.189
4. Install and start a MongoDB server on my VPS.
5. Install node of latest release on my VPS.
6. Clone my RESTful code to my VPS.
7. Start RESTful service with command 'node app.js'.
   [image]

**ISSUE**:

I can't get any response after sending request.(But it works fine on my localhost.)
[image]

**How can I start a RESTful service correctly?**

Comment: Did you try to run the `app.js` on your localhost?

Comment: Yes. I have tested several times and it works very fine.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a static content(style.css) so we can rule out the ip doesn't work?

Comment: Try checking your VPS firewall. Sometime firewall blocks request on several ports

Comment: Ok, I have pasted my Github link on my description. My nodejs code: https://github.com/HotHunter/VirginBlog/tree/develop/Server

Comment: Have you ever tried checking if the http request even reaches the server?

Comment: Do you not need to use forever.js to keep the server running?

I am not sure if this is just something you need to do on amazon ec2 and other elastic container services or on your vps too.

Comment: @schroffl I didn't try this yet. How can I test if request reaches the server?

Comment: @JonD I have tried 'nohup' command to keep the server running. It dose not solve my problem too.

Comment: @HoangDo Thanks! I will try that.

Comment: @ErumHuang Could you maybe add a `res.end('It works!')` in [Line 24](https://github.com/HotHunter/VirginBlog/blob/develop/Server/router/article.js#L24) of article.js? Because my request times out (but it works on your local computer, right?)

Comment: @schroffl Thank you! I found the solution. The firewall blocks requests. I solved that.

Comment: @HoangDo Thank you very much! I opened up the port, and it works~!

Comment: @ErumHuang glad it helped xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it is the firewall blocks the requests.

**Solution(For CentOS 7):**

1. Find out whether the firewall blocks the port, to list opening ports:

   `$ firewall-cmd --list-all`
2. If the list dose not contain the port your service needs, open up it use these commands:

   `$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent`

   `$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload`

> More details, reference to this post:
>   http://ask.xmodulo.com/open-port-firewall-centos-rhel.html